# Plotly: Boxplot doesn't show horizontal boxes with both x and y are given a list/array

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

Totally new to Plotly. Found a problem while I was playing around with the plotly boxplot. I was trying to draw two horizontal boxes by specifying x and y with an array and a list, respectively. One lies at y=1, the other lies at y=2. The code is the below：

```
trace1=go.Box(x=np.random.randn(100),y=[1]*100,boxpoints='all')
trace2=go.Box(x=np.random.randn(100),y=[2]*100,boxpoints='all')
figure=go.Figure(data=[trace1,trace2])
figure.show()
```

But I got no boxes, only has data points.
I tried the same code only with x and y switched, plotted two vertical boxes no problem. Not sure where the problem is, any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was a bit puzzled by this myself, and I can't tell you *why* it happens, but I can tell you *how* to fix it. Just add:

```
figure.update_traces(orientation='h')
```

And you'll get this plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
trace1=go.Box(x=np.random.randn(100),y=[1]*100, boxpoints = 'all')
trace2=go.Box(x=np.random.randn(100),y=[2]*100,boxpoints= 'all')
figure=go.Figure(data=[trace1,trace2])
figure.update_traces(orientation='h')
figure.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! Been struggling on this the whole afternoon.....

Comment: @Claire You're welcome! Please consider marking my suggestion as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @vestland, how to make trace0 appear above trace1?

Comment: @AndrewFount Not sure exactly what you mean. Please consider sharing some more details and post it as a new question, and I'll make sure to take a look.

Comment: @vestland, trace0 (blue box plot) is added first to the figure. How to show it above the red box plot, not below?

Comment: @AndrewFount You can change the order of the data with `figure.data = figure.data[::-1]`

Comment: @vestland, notice that the legend is written correctly. If I change the order of the data, then trace0 will be written under trace1.